# Visual Studio 2019 using path issue

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2019

In this project, I created a base repository class for Entity Framework (EfEntityRepositoryBase). **Initially it was located in (DataAccess.Concrete). Later i moved it to Core project.** My problem here is Visual Studio still sees it in (DataAccess.Concrete) but it is actually in (Core.DataAccess.EntityFramework).

Screenshot below shows solution explorer and pop up showing wrong path.

[image]

I tried clean rebuild, manually writing correct path but VS doesn't seem to recognize (Core.DataAccess) exists.

Comment: You're confusing `namespace` with projects. A project's name is irrelevant.

Comment: If you just moved the file without editing it, the namespace won't have changed. Look in the file and it will still have a `namespace .....` line at the top.

Comment: @DavidG this was the issue, fixed it now. Will remember next time, thanks.

Comment: I would recommend removing this question now since it's basically a "typo" question now.

Comment: It isn't some typo issue. Your answer provides information, VS not automatically updates namespace which leads to confusion. Other people who make same mistake may benefit from this post.

Comment: "Other people who make same mistake may benefit from this post." - no, they won't.

Answer (score 1):

Use the built-in refactoring tools to fix the namespace.

> Place your cursor in the namespace name.
> Press `Ctrl`+`.` to trigger the Quick Actions and Refactorings menu.
> Select Change namespace to <folder name>.

[Sync namespace and folder name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/sync-namespace-and-folder-name?view=vs-2019)